# how do i use fuse to mount a file in a compressed file as a symlink

Tags: linux, compression, symbolic-link, fuse, xz

i have a directory full of .xz files, each containing a single file (not tar).

uncompressed, the directory is 23GiB. (*.xml)

compressed, the directory is 1GiB. (*.xml.xz)

how do i fool the filesystem into thinking that each file is uncompressed, without the .xz extension?

i understand this could be slow, but time isn't an issue here, seamlessness is.

i understand that with the fuse library, i could do it, but i don't understand how. at least, i could mount the uncompressed file as a directory, but not as a file.

any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Idea: move `*.xml` files to a filesystem with compression. If the compression ratio turns out to be poor, maybe [this trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/625957/108618) will help.

Comment: i don't want to use btrfs, but that's an interesting trick. really, i want to keep the compression ratio that xz has on these files and mount using fuse.